# The easiest way to build custom logger in SLF4J?

Tags: java, slf4j, jcifs

I'm working on a project which will run on Jenkins pipeline as a step, which employes `jcifs-ng`. As `jcifs-ng` uses `SLF4J` for logging propose, I want to write a custom logger which can redirect all logging output of `jcifs-ng` to Jenkins logging callback.

My current idea is creating a new class which extends `SimpleLogger` with the corresponding `LoggerFactory`. However, it seems I have to overload nearly every public methods provided by `SimpleLogger` to redirect the output. Is there an easy way to do this within one hundred lines of code?